# Embedded view based on values from radio button

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have in Lotus a radio button called Selection with thesevalues :

Enter choices (one per line):
PartID
ItemDescription

In an embeddedview I have this formula as Embedded selection:

```
@If((Selection="PartID");
    "OrderregelsCategorizedByPartID";
    "OrderregelsCategorizedByItemDescription"
)
```

Show single category I have this formula:

```
@If((Selection="PartID");
    PartID;
    ItemDescription
)
```

But it does not work how come??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulas are executed only when document is opened. Later changes in radio button have no effect.

As a workaround you could reopen the document and memorize the radio button setting.

Comment: thanks. Is it also possible that I first get a dialogbox with a form in which i can select an option if I then press Ok that i then see the embeddedview? How can i do that??

Comment: Set an Environment variable in dialog box and use it in embedded view formulas.

Comment: You might also want to look into composite applications. See https://youtu.be/w3ddfZuX4Wc?list=PL282DA34A32B93B13